# Why is this limit equal to $0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have

> $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n^2}{2^n}}$

What I think is that $n^2\to\infty$ and $2^n\to\infty$, therefore we have $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ equals  indefineable. But Wolphram says that the limit is $0$.

Comment: I think the reason is that $2^n$ grows much faster than $n^2$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: And, by the same token, $n/n$ has no limit. CVD

Comment: You're being asked to compute $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n} $$ You're **not** being asked to compute $$\frac{(+\infty)^2}{2^{+\infty}}$$ Evaluating the limit by plugging in only works when the function is continuous; division is not continuous anywhere where you'd get an indeterminate form.

Comment: @hurkyl: this function is continuous, just plugging in doesn't work that often!

Comment: @Alessandro: While $n^2$ and $2^n$ are indeed continuous at $n = +\infty$, $x/y$ is *not* continuous at $x=y=+\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Apply L'Hospital twice, remembering that $2^n=e^{n \log(2)}$. You will quicly notice that there is a point where the numerator is a constant while the denominator still contains the exponential.

Answer (score 2):

Just because an expression has the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ it does't mean that the limit doesn't exist.

Take for example $$0=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{n^2}$$

which is also of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Concerning the limit you ask for:

Can you show that $\frac{n^2}{2^n}<\frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ big enough?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{2^n}{n^2}=\frac{(1+1)^n}{n^2} = \frac{1+n+n^2/2+n^3/6+\cdot\cdot\cdot}{n^2}$

So, $\frac{n^2}{2^n}$ varies as $\frac{1}{n+\text{higher powers of n}}$